# Appear in Emulator perfectly but not on real device

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-emulator

I try to run my app in real device however this is the problem:

[it looks like this in my emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXoTz.png)

[but it looks like this when i try to real device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LNjr.png)

see the link for reference.

what should be the problem?

here my code for the layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/test_image"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/menu_display_image"
            android:src="@drawable/iinterior"></ImageView>

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:background="#AA000000"></View>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top|right"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/text_goes_here"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="30dp" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fragment_button_center"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:background="@drawable/butt_purple"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:shadowColor="@android:color/white"
            android:shadowDx="1"
            android:shadowDy="1"
            android:shadowRadius="10"
            android:text="@string/add_to_my_menu"
            android:textSize="18dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fragment_button_left"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:background="@drawable/butt_other"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:shadowColor="@android:color/white"
            android:shadowDx="1"
            android:shadowDy="1"
            android:shadowRadius="10"
            android:text="View Order State"
            android:textSize="18dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/restaurant_description"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Tell us in detail about the device versions and details of your emulator and real device

Comment: Post the layout for the container please. This is only the layout for the fragment on the right.

Comment: I run it on both Marshmallow version.

Comment: @IshitaSinha I cant post the right layout. I don't know why. but its more all about viewpageradapter.

Comment: Could you explain how you inflate the list on the left and the details on the right of the screen? You have only posted the layout for the details screen, not for the list screen. I need the layout which holds both these list and details screens together.